# Field repositorio required a Bean of Type That Could not be found - JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I actually have this project in GitHub https://github.com/felloz/personsService

This project is a service that connect to the MySQL server to extract data and show me to be consumed for a frontend system. The problem is that when I run my project I'm receiving this error:

```html
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repositorio in com.example.demo.PersonServiceImp required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.PersonRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.PersonRepository' in your configuration.

Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 7.828 s
Finished at: 2020-05-11T12:39:32-04:00
Final Memory: 20M/228M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project demo: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Im new working with java/spring, any help its appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

edit:
update the parent version:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositorio'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.example.demo.PersonRepository.delete(int)! No property delete found for type Person!

Comment: try extending from `JpaRepository`. Also, `void delete(int)` is an invalid repository method signature - try commenting it out and rerun

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.demo.DemoApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/example/demo/PersonService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: mvn clean install

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositorio'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.Person com.example.demo.PersonRepository.findOne(int)! No property findOne found for type Person!

Comment: Could be something that i need to declare in the main class?

Comment: "No property findOne found for type Person!" - `Person findOne(int)` is also invalid. You can only override signatures which are present in the super interface - `JpaRepository`. And btw, there's no need to override them, you can remove them all, they are already in the `JpaRepository`

Comment: I would like to fix the problem with org.springframework.data.repository.Repository

Comment: then you have to use an older version of spring, probably like 1.8.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

The interface you are extending should be JpaRepository or CrudRepository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    List<Person>findAll();
    Person findOne(int id);
    Person save(Person p);
    void delete(int id);
}
```

And you need to add :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: boot doesn't require it as far as I know

Comment: incompatible types: Repository cannot be converted to Annotation

Comment: I have added more details. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependecy in your pom.xml.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field